# C: It is possible to pass variables to a function that request a struct so when the function is called these variables are wrapped into a struct?

Tags: c, function, struct

I have a function that request a struct.

```
struct test{
    const int a;
    const int b;
};

void testFunction(struct test mytest)
{
    //code
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way of passing two ints to the function so the process of calling it wraps those two ints into a struct.

Something like:

```
int main()
{
    //function call with some sort of wrapping system...
    testFunction({1,2});
}
```

Is there a way to the *{1,2}* wrapping part?

(If there is... Could be also done with functions that request pointer to structs?)

Thanks in advance,

Juan

Comment: Do some reading about [*compound literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Comment: Is this what you ask for? `testFunction((struct test){1,2});`

Comment: Aside: [un-learn `void main()`](https://ideone.com/j4dD6J)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `testFunction` as you declare it, `void testFunction(struct mytest test)`, can be called with:

```
testFunction((struct mytest) {1,2});
```

This uses a *compound literal*, which has the form:

```
(type) { initializers... }
```

Used in this way, it creates a temporary object and passes its value to the function.

For a function that takes a pointer to a structure, such as `void testFunction(struct test *mytest)`, you can pass the address of a compound literal with:

```
testFunction(& (struct mytest) {1,2});
```

or:

```
testFunction((struct mytest []) {1,2});
```

The lifetime of a compound literal inside a function ends when execution of its associated block (the innermost `{...}` that enclose it) ends. It has automatic storage duration.

A compound literal outside of any function has static storage duration; it exists for the lifetime of the program.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb you should avoid passing structs by value. Furthermore, the kind of feature you are looking for is probably only suitable for functions that do not modify the parameters passed, meaning it should use const correctness:

```
void testFunction(const struct test* mytest);
```

This could be called with a temporary struct known as *compound literal* in standard C. (Similar to the term anonymous objects in other languages.)

```
testFunction(&(struct test){1,2});
```

where `(struct test){1,2}` is the compound literal and we take its address to pass on to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

struct test{
     int a;
     int b;
};

void testFunction(struct test *mytest)
{
    printf("a.........:%d",(*mytest).a);
}

int main()
{
    //function call with some sort of wrapping system...
    testFunction(&(struct test){1,2});
}
```

Works for me.

Comment: See Lundin's answer for improvement - you almost certainly want to pass a pointer to `const`.